# Indicate to which cell should data be extracted

Tags: excel, vba

I use this formula Function

```vb
Function ExtractDomain(ByVal URL As String) As String
'Update 20140904
    If InStr(URL, "//") Then
        URL = Mid(URL, InStr(URL, "//") + 2)
    End If
    If Left(URL, 4) Like "[Ww][Ww][Ww0-9]." Then
        URL = Mid(URL, 5)
    End If
    ExtractDomain = Split(URL, "/")(0)
End Function
```

I have to indicate in the cell (Excel) where to extract it.
For example, URL is in cell E9, but in cell E15 I have to type =extractdomain(e9) in cell E15.

How could I do this in VBA, so that the formula in the end says "Ok, take the URL from E9, extract the domain and then paste that given domain in E15?

I can lock cells and formulas, but I would like this in VBA to ensure that users do not delete it by accident.

Comment: So `ExtractDomain` basically always return the domain in cell E9? Make a string variable (call it `URL` so you don't have to change the rest of the code) then assign `Cells(9,5)` (fully qualify it so that you can use it in any Worksheet) value to it at the start of the function. Remove the parameter as well.

Comment: Hey Raymod, thanks for the advice.  I know it is not very important, but woks like this E9 = is where you paste URL, E13 is the cell where domain should come as a result, so yes, E13 is the place where I want my E9 to return. Mind telling me how to do that part? Formula I found online and I am far from VBA user. Gracias

Comment: To place the result in E13 type `=ExtractDomain()` into E13.  Providing you've removed `ByVal URL As String` from the function name and put it in the code body as @RaymondWu suggests.

Comment: Create an handler on the sheet for the event Worksheet_Change. In the event, check if the change concern the cell E9, then put the result of ExtractDomain in the E15 cell

Comment: @Boris is E15 always going to show the domain of the URL in E9? If so then transferring the code (and some slight changes) to `Worksheet_Change` event will be better as you don't have to enter the formula in E15 and it will always be updated to the URL in E9.

Comment: @RaymondWu E9 is always URL (pasted) and E15 is always =extractdomain(E9) but I am trying to get rid of =extractdomain(E9) because users can delete the formula and then it won't work. So my idea/question is just to current code, to add the line that say, check cell E9, check URL, extract domain and paste it in E15 (with E15 not having =extractdomain)

Comment: @Boris I just updated my answer, please check it and see if it works (untested as I have no access to computer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment:

1. Declare a new variable to store the value of cell `E9`, I have named it `URL` so that the rest of the code do not need to change its reference. (Please change `"Sheet1"` to the sheet name where cell `E9` storing the URL is)
2. Remove the parameter `ByVal URL As String` so that you don't have to provide a cell as an argument to the function)

Update - Paste this in the worksheet module (in the VBE, double click the sheet that you want it to work then paste the below code)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
'Update 20140904
    Dim URL As String
    URL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 5).Value 'Change the sheet name to the correct one
    
    If InStr(URL, "//") Then
        URL = Mid(URL, InStr(URL, "//") + 2)
    End If
    If Left(URL, 4) Like "[Ww][Ww][Ww0-9]." Then
        URL = Mid(URL, 5)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15,5).Value = Split(URL, "/")(0)
     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now it should update automatically whenever you make changes in the worksheet and no formula is needed in E15